# Воспроизведение видео в Windows Forms из ресурсов

Tags: c#, winforms, видео

Есть ли способы воспроизведения видео, загруженного в ресурсы, на форму? Я пробовал библиотеку `Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.dll`, но при попытке загрузки видео на форму, вся программа зависала, помогало только выйти из отладки. Также пробовал `WindowsMediaPlayer`, но с ним воспроизводится только звук и из ресурсов видео добавить не возможно, нужен путь к самому видео на ПК.

Comment: Предоставьте код, который приводит к зависанию.

Comment: И что вам мешает достать видео из ресурса и положить в файловую систему в рантайме?

Comment: @iluxa1810, https://paste.ofcode.org/K3iTQJd9fwBM2LsPRvBj8D. Зависает на моменте присваивания к переменной video самого видео. А как положить видео в файловую систему?

Comment: [Извлечение ресурсов в приложениях для настольных систем](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/resources/retrieving-resources-in-desktop-apps)

Comment: @iluxa1810, У меня получилось это - https://paste.ofcode.org/LBkAHJ3jtYRb2tZpSc8XQf. Звук идет, видео нет

Comment: С этим уже разобрался. Мне теперь нужно, чтобы работало и видео и звук, но пока что работает только звук, показывает то, что показывает при проигрывании обычной аудиозаписи через плеер

Comment: Если открыть этот NaZare_temp.mp4 в обычном Windows Media Player, видео воспроизводится? Если нет, то и с ActiveX ничего не выйдет